# Install NativeHost for Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an chrome extension, which opens Terminal process started by NativeHost json file. To install this json file on the system i need to copy it in NativeMessagHost folder in OSx and In Windows, Change some registry for local user.
In the sample extension code i can see, the installation of such thing is done using .bat/.sh scripts but that does not seem user friendly because to a non-techy guy opening a terminal and running these scripts can be a nightmare.
Is there any other way to install these NativeHost.json in a userfriendly way?

Source code for  NativeHost.json can be (taken from chrome extension sample code):

```
{
  "name": "com.google.chrome.example.echo",
  "description": "Chrome Native Messaging API Example Host",
  "path": "HOST_PATH",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://<ID>"
  ]
}
```

and .sh looks like:

```
set -e

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
if [ "$(uname -s)" == "Darwin" ]; then
  if [ "$(whoami)" == "root" ]; then
    TARGET_DIR="/Library/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts"
  else
    TARGET_DIR="$HOME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts"
  fi
else
  if [ "$(whoami)" == "root" ]; then
    TARGET_DIR="/etc/opt/chrome/native-messaging-hosts"
  else
    TARGET_DIR="$HOME/.config/google-chrome/NativeMessagingHosts"
  fi
fi

HOST_NAME=com.google.chrome.example.echo

# Create directory to store native messaging host.
mkdir -p "$TARGET_DIR"

# Copy native messaging host manifest.
cp "$DIR/$HOST_NAME.json" "$TARGET_DIR"

# Update host path in the manifest.
HOST_PATH=/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal

ESCAPED_HOST_PATH=${HOST_PATH////\\/}
sed -i -e "s/HOST_PATH/$ESCAPED_HOST_PATH/" "$TARGET_DIR/$HOST_NAME.json"

# Set permissions for the manifest so that all users can read it.
chmod o+r "$TARGET_DIR/$HOST_NAME.json"

echo "Native messaging host $HOST_NAME has been installed."
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the samples are just that - rough and minimal samples.

If you're distributing a native host app, you're expected to have some sort of installer (an installer program or .msi for Windows, something like a .deb/whatever package for Linux and so on) that can take care of that. In fact, such an installer can even [trigger the installation of the extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions).

How to make one is outside the scope of the question, but that's *the idea* - there are tools that can generate installers or packages that provide a familiar, user-friendly way of installing software.

Note: it's unreasonable to expect a **portable** solution. You'll need separate installers for separate platforms - but then again, your **Native host** must differ anyway.